# How to derive angle of rotation based on Gyroscope readings?

Tags: android-sensors, angle, gyroscope

I am trying derive the angle of rotation based on Gyroscope readings in my android application. I tried using rotation matrix for orientation values but they are unreliable. Is there a way that I can figure out the angle of rotation based on Gyro readings?

Comment: This will inherently have poor accuracy - a gyro is a rate sensor, and integrating rate to obtain amount accumulates the effect of inevitable error.

Comment: True! I am working with orientation values anyway. Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"I tried using rotation matrix for orientation values but they are unreliable."* Could you detail the problems with these values, please? I am asking this because it may mean that there is something wrong with the sensors, and you should look into that and not into deriving a new algorithm to compute orientation.

Comment: They changed too rapidly for me to do anything with them. I made a low pass filter function and passed the values through it. It is much smoother now. I think I can use them now